# Is there any WCS service example with Mapserver?

Tags: mapserver, wcs

I want to publish tiff image in browser using Mapserver, for obtaining elevation data. Is there any resource or example regarding this.

Comment: I'm not aware of any browser that natively supports a tiff image (such that you can view the image in the web page).  You can use MapServer WCS to supply a Tiff for download and/or use a Tiff as data input to supply a browser viewable image such as gif, jpeg or png.  Can you clarify your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a MapServer service (version 7.1-dev) providing a WCS 2.0 service using GeoTiffs as the data source.

Here we have a `GetCoverage` request for an `image/png` output format:

http://194.66.252.155/cgi-bin/BGS_EMODnet_bathymetry/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&CoverageId=BGS_EMODNET_AegeanLevantineSeas-MCol&format=image/png&

Clicking on the above link should result in an image being displayed in your browser.

Here's the same request but his time we ask for an `image/tiff` as the output format.

http://194.66.252.155/cgi-bin/BGS_EMODnet_bathymetry/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&CoverageId=BGS_EMODNET_AegeanLevantineSeas-MCol&format=image/tiff&

Clicking on the above link will probably result in your browser asking you to save the image to your PC, where you will need to view it in some image software like http://www.gimp.org/downloads/.

Instead of using a browser to view the Tiff output of the service an alternative would be to use QGIS and the QgsWcsClient2 plugin.